# How to change file path where the Debug Toolbar's debugger files are stored?

Tags: craft4, commands, debug

According to [Pull Request #10825](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/pull/10825) for Craft 4, you can override the filesystem and path where the debugger files are stored for the Debug Toolbar. In the absence of using a separate filesystem, I'd like to be able to store these somewhere inside of the @runtime/temp folder since there is a `clear-caches/temp-files` command to clear this directory but not one specifically for the `@runtime/debug` folder.

So far, I've added a `config/debug.php` file that contains the following:

```php
return [
    'dataPath' => '@runtime/temp/debug',
];
```

But the only effect this seems to have is 1) when it's set to `@runtime/debug` the files are created successfully in their normal location, or 2) for any other value the files aren't created whatsoever.

I looked into adding an action to the [ClearCaches Utility](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/utilities/ClearCaches.php) specifically for clearing the debug folder, but after coming across the above pull request I wasn't sure how to implement it in such a way that would account for custom filesystems, so I thought just moving it to within another folder that's cleared when running a `clear-caches` command would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that what I had was actually creating the files but in a `@runtime/temp/debug` folder inside the web root. Parsing that string with `App::parseEnv()` did the trick, and the debugging files are now created successfully inside `/storage/runtime/temp/debug` and cleared with the `clear-caches/temp-files` console command:

```php
use craft\helpers\App;

return [
    'dataPath' => App::parseEnv('@runtime/temp/debug')
];
```